# Any application to identify if a video is available in Netflix / HBO / Amazon Prime Video?

Tags: chrome, web-browser

Oftentimes when I want to watch a movie or a series, I have to lookup across Netflix then HBO then Amazon Prime Video.

Is there any application or web I could search for a specific movie or series and would tell me if that's available in one of these online platforms? I know there are other streaming platforms, I mention the above as these are the ones I'm more interested to.

Also, browser plugins for IMDB webpage stating availability would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.canistream.it claims to check some popular streaming sites but does not seem to work very well for me (does not load actual availablitity data).

Answer (score 1):

The canistream suggestion posted by Erik didn't work for me, but Google guided me to https://www.justwatch.com and it seems to fit like a glove. Will leave the question open to see if anyone comes up with a Chrome plugin that integrates with IMDB on the next couple of days, otherwise will stick to JustWatch.